# Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Are the monoids $(X,\max), (X,\min)$ isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. How do I make sure if the monoids $(X,\max), (X,\min)$ are isomorphic? I can see that it's possible to define a bijective function between these two, but can this function also be homomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally let $X=\{0, 1,\ldots, n\}$ (note that I've added $0$) and define

$$f:X\to X$$
$$f(k)=n-k$$

Simply speaking $f$ reverses the order.

Then for any $a, b\in X$ we have

$$f\big(\max(a, b)\big)=n - \max(a,b)=\min(n-a, n-b)=\min\big(f(a), f(b)\big)$$
$$f\big(\min(a, b)\big)=n - \min(a,b)=\max(n-a, n-b)=\max\big(f(a), f(b)\big)$$

Those equalities follow from the fact that $a\leq b$ if and only if $-a\geq -b$.

So $f$ preserves both monoid structures and is invertible with $f^{-1}=f$. Indeed

$$f(f(k))=f(n-k)=n-(n-k)=k$$

Thus it is an isomorphism.

Comment: If we have for example a>b, then do we have to note that max(a,b)=max(a,a)? Because otherwise this function wouldn't be injective?

Comment: @user391135 This function is injective, because it is invertible. And it is invertible because $f\circ f=1$, i.e. it is the inverse of itself (indeed $f(f(k))=f(n-k)=n-(n-k)=k$). On the other hand, yeah $\max(a, a)=a$ and $\max(a,b)=a$ if $a\geq b$. These properties are not related to $f$ though.